# Curl with random IP v6 from /64 subnet: ndppd, ip neighbour or routing not working

Tags: debian, routing, proxy, ipv6, bind

I'm trying to setup random IPv6 proxies pool on my server /64 subnet like this: https://github.com/zu1k/http-proxy-ipv6-pool, but `curl --interface 2a05:541:108:26::2 google.com` not working (endless loading). On standard address all working well: `curl --interface 2a05:541:108:26::1 google.com` returns valid content.

Linux distro: Ubuntu 22

`ip -6 a` output:

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 state UNKNOWN qlen 1000
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,ALLMULTI,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 state UP qlen 1000
    inet6 2a05:541:108:26::1/48 scope global
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::5054:ff:fe1f:7217/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

`cat /etc/network/interfaces` output:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
    address   81.19.139.62
    netmask   255.255.255.0
    gateway   81.19.139.1
    hwaddress ether 52:54:00:1F:72:17
    dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 1.1.1.1
iface eth0 inet6 static
    address   2a05:541:108:26::1
    netmask   48
    gateway   2a05:541:108::1
    dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 1.1.1.1
```

inet6 routing table:

```
2a05:541:108::/48 dev eth0 proto kernel metric 256 pref medium
fe80::/64 dev eth0 proto kernel metric 256 pref medium
default via 2a05:541:108::1 dev eth0 metric 1024 onlink pref medium
local ::1 dev lo table local proto kernel metric 0 pref medium
anycast 2a05:541:108:: dev eth0 table local proto kernel metric 0 pref medium
local 2a05:541:108:26::1 dev eth0 table local proto kernel metric 0 pref medium
local 2a05:541:108:26::/64 dev eth0 table local metric 1024 pref medium 
anycast fe80:: dev eth0 table local pr`oto kernel metric 0 pref medium
local fe80::5054:ff:fe1f:7217 dev eth0 table local proto kernel metric 0 pref medium
ff00::/8 dev eth0 table local metric 256 pref medium
```

sysctl.conf ending:

```
net.ipv6.conf.all.forwarding=1
net.ipv6.conf.eth0.forwarding=1
net.ipv6.conf.all.proxy_ndp=1
net.ipv6.conf.eth0.proxy_ndp=1
```

ndppd config:

```
proxy eth0 {
        rule 2a05:541:108:26::/64 {
                static
        }
}
```

I tried directly add neighbour via command `ip neigh add proxy 2a05:541:108:26::2 dev eth0`, but its also not working.

Comment: Hello! Do you have any working solution so far?